# Excel VBA remove commas and double spaces within strings

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a column with company names in it. I want to trim the names as well as remove commas and double spaces within them. The code I currently have gets the trim done. But I cannot figure out how to remove commas and double spaces ex: Big Company, LLC ex: Big  Company
This is my current code

```
Dim tCompName As String
tCompName = "E1:E" & Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
Range(tCompName) = Evaluate("IF(" & tCompName & "="""","""",Trim(" & tCompName & "))")
```

Any help is appreciated. And just a fyi, doing this in VBA because have to do it often along with formatting things that I already have automated in this macro.

Comment: `TRIM` should remove the double spaces. All you need to do is add a `SUBSTITUTE` to remove the commas. Or use `Range.Replace` for the commas and `Application.Trim` for the double spaces.

Comment: ^^^^`Range(tCompName) = Evaluate("IF(" & tCompName.Address(0,0) & "="""","""",Trim(SUBSTITUTE(" & tCompName.Address(0,0)  & ","","","" "")))")`

Comment: @ScottCraner I tried the code you supplied. I get an error when I run it "Compile error: Invalid qualifier" and it highlights the first tCompName. It runs when I remove .Address(0,0) but results in all the cells being #VALUE!

Comment: `Range(tCompName) = Evaluate("IF(" & Range(tCompName).Address(0,0) & "="""","""",Trim(SUBSTITUTE(" & Range(tCompName).Address(0,0)  & ","","","" "")))")`

Comment: @ScottCraner That worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: Isn't `Range(tCompName).Address(0,0)` just the same as `tCompName` ?